# Set UICollectionViewCell according to the size of UICollectionView using Autolayouts, Size Classes in Storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, uicollectionview, size-classes

I have a `UICollectionView` which I can easily set in `Storyboard` with `Autolayout` and `Size Classes` enabled. Now I also want to set `UICollectionViewCell` and `UICollectionReusableView`i.e my header. I am not able to set them inside CollectionView in Storyboard, as when I drag the Cell while pressing `control` I don't get any options to set height/width. So, I am unable to put `contraints` on `UICollectionViewCell` inside storyboard. Right now, there size is fixed for all devices. I know how to do it programatically, but I would like to do it inside Storyboard. Please suggest how to do it? I have looked into other Stackoverflow posts but they are doing it programatically.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't achieve what you are looking for from the StoryBoard

For dynamic size of the UIcollectionviewCell you have to use **UICollectionViewFlowLayout or UICollectionviewLayout.**

There is no way to change the Size only from the StoryBoard. You can better study about UICollectionViewFlowLayout

- https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CollectionViewBasics/CollectionViewBasics.html

Hope it will help you to better Understand.